# UDP socket, select one of multiple clients

Tags: sockets, udp

here's what I'm trying to do:

I have 4 clocks and one PC on the network. I (PC) want to get the time from any of the clocks.

The idea:

Every clock uses UDP Broadcast (broadcast because I don't know the PC's IP). The PC gets a first dataset(time) and from then on only looks at datasets from this clock. (To not get confused by slight timedifferences between the clocks)

Clocks=Clients:

 - socket

 - bind to port 1234

 - sendto(broadcast,'1234')

PC=Server

 - socket

 - bind to port 1234

 - recvfrom(data,client_addr) //extract client_addr from first received data

 - connect(client_addr) //to only receive data from this client

 - recvfrom()

1: Is this the correct way to do this? Or is there a better option?

2: What can I do, if I want more than one application on the PC to get the time-data? Can I just copy the code and use it? My impression was, that port 1234 is now blocked from the first application that gets the bind.
(I guess SO_REUSEADDR won't work because only ONE application then gets the data AND I don't know which one it is going to be)

Regards

Comment: I'm not sure what your application is, but it sounds like it might be what ptpd does -- precisely synchronizing clocks across a LAN.  If so, maybe you want to just run ptpd?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: Thanks for this hint! Looks like something to think about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1: Is this the correct way to do this?

Yes.

> Or is there a better option?

Can't think of one off-hand.

> 2: What can I do, if I want more than one application on the PC to get the time-data?

Use `SO_REUSEADDR`.

> Can I just copy the code and use it?

Yes.

> My impression was, that port 1234 is now blocked from the first application that gets the bind.

No.

> (I guess SO_REUSEADDR won't work because only ONE application then gets the data AND I don't know which one it is going to be)

Wrong guess. Why guess about it at all? Why not try it? Much more reliable than guessing, and quicker than asking questions here too.

Comment: about SO_REUSEADDR:
"Also, if two sockets are bound to the same port the behavior is undefined as to which port will receive packets." or "Once the second socket has successfully bound, the behavior for all sockets bound to that port is indeterminate."
I tried it now and it worked, but I am a little bit worried about the stability because of the undefined behavior.
Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Michael As the packets are incoming as broadcasts I would expect them to be delivered to everybody, but you will certainly have to test and verify. If that doesn't work you will have to make other arrangements. Can you use UDP multicast instead of broadcast?

Comment: As I said: from my testing it works. But I'm just worried/curious about the stability/portability/theoretical correctness...
What would be other arrangements?
Why do you suggest to use multicast? Is it more suitable?

Comment: @Michael Multicast is more suitable from every point of view, one of them being that the behaviour you want is specified, even by Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks EJP! So the correct way to go is via Multicast. MSDN: "The exception to this non-deterministic behavior is multicast sockets. If two sockets are bound to the same interface and port and are members of the same multicast group, data will be delivered to both sockets, rather than an arbitrarily chosen one."

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.kohala.com/start/mcast.api.txt) clarifies as well: "More than one process may bind to the same SOCK_DGRAM UDP port if the bind() is preceded by setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR).
In this case, every incoming **multicast or broadcast** UDP datagram destined to the shared port is delivered to all sockets bound to the port. For backwards
compatibility reasons, THIS DOES NOT APPLY TO INCOMING UNICAST DATAGRAMS -- unicast datagrams are never delivered to more than one socket, regardless of how many sockets are bound to the datagram's destination port."

Comment: @Michael Quite so. IMHO the 'backwards compatibility' referred to was really a Windows bug. What the point was of allowing SO_REUSEADDR and then not letting it actually *work,* i.e. deliver packets, is a complete mystery to me.